# Oracle Backup and Recovery

Tags: backup, oracle-10g, rman

My backed up archivelog file format is 'al_%U'. During recovery it shows the following error:

```
RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown log: thread 1 seq 17 lowscn 671075
```

How to determine which archivelog is necessary? In RMAN format I can't indicate thread and seq  yes(for simply finding archivelog during this error)?

I should have that archivelog... If I really have that archive log how to indicate it to my database?

Thank You a lot...

I wil be very glad if you provide me with some book that clearly explains backup and recovery strategy and examples(In Oracle)...

GREAT THANKS!!...

**Partial Answer of my question:**

If I type

```
RMAN> list backup;
```

It shows me the **thread**, **Seq** and Low **SCN** of the logfiles in the backup set :D great!!

But there is one missing archivelog backup, what to do? How to register?(I am not using Catalog!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [use the `catalog`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta008.htm#RCMRF109) command in RMAN to make the file known to the database (don't worry, this does not depend on a [recovery catalog](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28273/rcmsynta013.htm)!)

Comment: @"Jack Douglas" Thank you, I also found it (happy) but ERROR:

RMAN-03009: failure of catalog command on default channel..
ORA-19698 "achivelogName" is from different database: id=169869321, db_name=Bd?LORCL

DATABASE NAME SHOULD BE ORCL not Bd?LORCL...What happened

Comment: is it possible that the archivelog file is indeed from another database as the error suggests?

Comment: @"Jack Douglas" No.. I was performing backups and recovery just for one database...very strange.. Also strange is db_name indicated in the error..What is "Bd?LORCL" very strange name..What happened don't know :? (Just for info My OS is Centos 5)

Comment: could the file be corrupt? Perhaps you can try [`alter system dump logfile`](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/DBverify-like-utility-for-archive-log-files,3)

Comment: @"Jack Douglas" I did this: catalog backuppiece 'archivelogFileName'...And worked! (I was using catalog archivelog)More correctly I have now another error(another sequence is requested) 
ERROR: media recovery requesting unknow log: thread 1 seq 19 lowscn 671317..

Comment: have you got some more backpieces to catalog? You can use `catalog` to catalog a whole directory at once (see `start with` in the page I linked)

Comment: Thank you @"Jack Douglas" ... I got to know many useful things from you...